What movie is the quote "Have I been here all night... alone?" "If you don't count me, yes." from?
In the song Ur Love by Senbeï, there is what sounds like a movie quote (my guess from the language is 40s or 50s, but I could be way off). Can you help me figure out what?

Woman: Have I been here all night ... alone?
Man: If you don't count me, yes.
Woman: So I spent the night here. With you?
Man: Well now *stammers* I don't know that I'd use those words, exactly, but uh, from a certain angle, yes.


If you use quotation marks in a google query it will look for an exact match. Thus googling "Have I been here all night ... alone" returns the movie as a first result (at least for me).

IMDb has the following from Roman Holiday (1953):

Princess Ann: Have I been here all night, alone?
Joe Bradley: If you don't count me, yes.
Princess Ann: So I've spent the night here - with you?
Joe Bradley: Well now, I-I don't know that I'd use those words exactly, but uh, from a certain angle, yes.

See 1:19:




From the script of the movie "Roman Holiday":

Have I been here all night... alone?
If you don't count me, yes.
So I've spent the night here... with you.
Well, now, I don't know|that I'd use those words exactly. But... from a certain angle... yes.


DV without comment on a documented and perfectly valid answer?!

Your answer came a full hour after the identical (in fact, slightly better formatted) answer above. Why do you feel it's worthy of upvotes?

Maybe because it has a link to the whole script?  That could have been a comment on the other answer.

It hasn't even got a link to the whole script. This is a link to a badly-processed subtitles file, converted to a PDF; that is just a link to a Google web app embedding the above. Here's an actual script.
